# How can I solve this challenging card counting problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

**A deck of 52 cards is shuffled and evenly split amongst 13 people(4 cards each). What is the probability that one of them has exactly 2 aces and 2 others have exactly 1 ace each?**

I feel like a good way to think about this would be to divide the number of ways to place 2 aces in one sequence of 4 cards and 1 ace in two sequences of 4 cards each by the number of ways to place 4 aces in 52 cards(52C4). I'm really confused about how to calculate the numerator though. Any insights on how to solve this? Would also appreciate general tips for solving more challenging counting problems.

Answer (score 7):

Let's implement the strategy you suggested.  If we look at sequences of cards, there are $\binom{52}{4}$ ways to select positions for the four aces.

If we divide these sequences into $13$ blocks of four cards each, there are $13$ ways to select the block which will contain two aces, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select two positions in that block for those two aces, $\binom{12}{2}$ ways to select which two of the remaining $12$ blocks will contain one ace each, and four ways to select a position in each of those blocks for the ace in those blocks.

> Hence, the probability that one person receives two of the four aces, while two other people each receive one ace when $13$ players each receive four cards is $$\frac{\dbinom{13}{1}\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{12}{2}\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{52}{4}}$$

Comment: Final value (for comparison with other answers): $$\frac{13\times6\times66\times4\times4}{270725} = \frac{82368}{270725} \approx 30.42\%$$

Answer (score 5):

First, let us find the probability that $A\spadesuit$ and $A\heartsuit$ are together, while the other two aces are separate.

- Each card can end up in one of $52$ equally likely positions. Given the location of $A\spadesuit$, there are $51$ remaining equally likely positions for $A\heartsuit$. There are $3$ of these locations which are in the same hand as $A\spadesuit$. Therefore, $P(\text{A$\spadesuit$ and A$\heartsuit$ in same hand})=1/17$.
- Next, we need $A\clubsuit$ to be in a different hand, conditional on the first bullet point. There are $50$ remaining positions for $A\clubsuit$. Two of these are in the same hand as $A\spadesuit$ and $A\heartsuit$, leaving $48$ valid positions, for a probability of $48/50$.
- Finally, a similar calculation shows that the conditional probability that $A\diamondsuit$ is in a different hand from all previous aces is $44/49$.

Multiplying these three probabilities together, we get the probability that  $A\spadesuit$ and $A\heartsuit$ are together, while the other two aces are separate. There are $\binom42$ total ways to choose the two aces that are together, so we have to multiply the above by $\binom42$ to account for all possibilities. The final answer is
$$
\binom{4}{2}\cdot \frac1{17}\cdot \frac{48}{50}\cdot \frac{44}{49}=\frac{6336}{20825}\approx 30.42\%
$$

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to count the ways for exactly three players to get at least one ace.

There are $\binom{13}3$ ways to pick three players.

There are $\binom{48}{8}$ ways to choose the non-aces for those three players.

There are $\frac{40!}{4!^{10}}$ to divide the remaining cards amongst the other ten players.

So if $M$ is the number of ways to divide $12$ cards, including four aces, amongst three players, so that each player gets at least one ace, the resulting probability is:

$$\frac{M\binom{48}8\binom{13}3\frac{40!}{4!^{10}}}{\frac{52!}{4!^{13}}}
=\frac{M4!^3\binom{48}{8}\binom{13}3}{52\cdot51\cdot\cdots\cdot 41}
=\frac{M4!^3\binom{13}{3}}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 8!}$$

There are a number of ways to compute $M.$ One ways is inclusion-exclusion, but it is probably easier to use a different technique for $M.$

Comment: $M = \binom 3 1 \binom 4 2 \binom 8 2 \binom 2 1 \binom 6 3 = 3 \times 6 \times 28 \times 2 \times 20 = 20160$. Indeed: choose which of the three players has two aces, choose which two aces this player has, choose which other 2 cards this player has, choose which of the other two players gets the smallest of the two remaining aces (using convention spades > hearts > diamonds > clubs), choose the other three cards of this player.

Comment: Finally: $$\frac{M \binom{13}{3} \binom{52}{8} \frac{40!}{4!^{10}}}{\frac{52!}{4!^{13}}} = \frac{55836441602809298289768017678017816368000000000000}{92024242230271040357108320801872044844750000000000} \approx 60.68\%$$

Comment: Yep, thanks, @stef

Comment: @Stef: This seems to be exactly double of the answer N. F. Taussig and I have got.

Comment: @tkf Great minds think alike! I just made that change.

Comment: Hurrrraaaaaaah Now with the fix we have: $$\frac{M\binom{48}8\binom{13}3\frac{40!}{4!^{10}}}{\frac{52!}{4!^{13}}}
=\frac{27998348080239966948506041805553962839680000000000}{92024242230271040357108320801872044844750000000000} = \frac{6336}{20825} \approx 30.42\%$$

Comment: @Stef: The answers now tally with mine, but what is the advantage of using more complex formulations to arrive at the same answer ?

Comment: @trueblueanil I don't think it's really more complex. If anything, I think this one is "more simple, less clever". This is something that happens a lot in probability problems that involve permutations: here we have 52 cards, among which only 4 are of interest, and we distribute it to players in hands of 4 cards, the order of which does not matter. And we want the probability of a certain subsets of permutations. So you can try to be smart about what matters and what doesn't matter, and only count permutations of what matters, or you can go more "bruteforce" and count all permutations.

Comment: The more "bruteforce" method will involve a much larger numerator, which will cancel out with a much larger denumerator, than the "smarter" methods; but it's not necessarily more complicated. Also note that when counting only the things that matter, it's sometimes easy to introduce errors because of issues that are not equiprobable. As a trivial example: when rolling two dice, often we don't care about the order of the dice, and consider that an issue of (3, 4) is equivalent to an issue of (4, 3), but it's easier to count them separately because {(3, 4), (4, 3)} is twice as likely as {(3,3)}.

Comment: @trueblueanil And since we have multiple people tackling the same problem here on this page, we might as well compare the numeric values of the answers to make sure that we all got the same result.

Comment: @Stef: Well, mine works out to $\dfrac{82368}{270725}= \dfrac{6336}{20825}$, which tallies with your answer.

Comment: @Stef: Also tallies with all responses that have provided a numeric answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are $13$ **groups** of $4$ each

- Choose $3$ groups which will have the aces: $\binom{13}3$
- From them, choose group with two aces, and place: $\binom32\binom42$
- Place one ace each in the two other groups:$\binom41\binom41$
- Putting the pieces together, $$Pr = {\binom{13}3\binom32\binom42\binom41\binom41\over\binom{52}4} = \dfrac{82368}{270725}= \dfrac{6336}{20825} \approx 0.3042 $$

---

Another way is to choose the "double" card in $\binom42$ ways, and place the four cards sequentially in proper groups, thus $$\left[\binom42\frac{52}{52}\frac3{51}\right]\frac{48}{50}\frac{44}{49}$$ where $\frac{52}{52}$, of course, could just have been omitted.

Answer (score 0):

There are 12 ways to choose 1 ace, 1 ace, and 2 aces (4!/1!1!2!).
For a given choice, the probability that they end up at the first, second, and third player respectively, is 1/13 * 1/13 * 4/52*3/51.
Now the is $12\cdot {11 \choose 2}$ ways to choose these 3 players.

You should work out the answer from this.

Comment: There are $13$ players.  Check your count for the number of ways to select the three players.

Comment: Also, you should check your claim that the probability that the aces end up at the first, second, and third player respectively, is $\frac{1}{13} \cdot \frac{1}{13} \cdot \frac{4}{52} \cdot \frac{3}{51}$.

Comment: You have left the answer unfinished, so please finish it and check whether it tallies with the other answers.